# Can I give android chrome a permission to play audio files when the screen is off?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio

I have several local JS HTML5 scripts on my android phone that play mp3 files or pure tones, but whenever I turn off the screen they stop running.
There are a few answers for this which are 4-7 years old, all of them essentially negative, due to security issues. However I would be happy even with away to give the browser a suitable permission to continue playing such audio files.